In LWC, Updated array values are not reflecting on UI. While modified values visible in console
JSON Structure:
uiData = [
  {
    "item": {
      "lineitem": {
        "discount__c": -43.774,
        "margin__c": 0.421,
        "product_cost__c": 206128.9403409091,
        "qty__c": 3,
        "sale_price__c": 207000.4528409091,
        "total_cost__c": 618386.821,
        "total_price__c": 621001.3585,
        "total_unit_price__c": 431928.9672
      }
    }
  }
]

LWC JS code:
updatedRow.lineitem.total_price__c = 100000;
this.uiData[index]['item'] = updatedRow;


Please read on how to ask a question on this site before posting your code: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Read Reactivity for Fields, Objects, and Arrays in the Lightning Web Components Developer Guide.  Reactivity refers to the UI reacting to data changes by updating the UI.  By default, only primitive values (string, integer, etc) and top level objects/arrays are reactive.  In your example, if you reassign uiData, it will be reactive, but changing the contents of the object is not reactive, unless you use the @track decorator.  From the linked docs:

To observe changes to the properties of an object or to the elements of an array, decorate the field with @track.
When a field is decorated with @track, Lightning Web Components tracks changes to the internal values of:

Plain objects created with {}
Arrays created with []



Thanks Jason Clark
